# Compilation won't stop due to package conflict, how to locate the problem in this case?

Tags: compiling, incompatibility, thmtools

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{create-theorem}
\CreateTheorem { theorem } {}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    Text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile it, the compilation never stops (possibly due to a conflict between `thmtools` and `create-theorem`), and the `.log` file is not complete, so I don't know how to find the reason that causes this behavior. Is there something that I can do in this case?

---

Here is the log file using `pdflatex`:

```
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-05-04> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks16
\thm@bodyfont=\toks17
\thm@headfont=\toks18
\thm@notefont=\toks19
\thm@headpunct=\toks20
\thm@preskip=\skip49
\thm@postskip=\skip50
\thm@headsep=\skip51
\dth@everypar=\toks21
) (/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/betas/create-theorem/create-theorem.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-05-04 L3 programming layer (loader) 
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-04-20 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
))
Package: l3keys2e 2022-01-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: create-theorem 2022/05/22 Initializing theorem-like environments with multilingual support
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/aliascnt.sty
Package: aliascnt 2018/09/07 v1.5 Alias counters (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/betas/crefthe/crefthe.sty
Package: crefthe 2022/05/13 Cross referencing with proper definite articles
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty
Package: cleveref 2018/03/27 v0.21.4 Intelligent cross-referencing
Package cleveref Info: `amsthm' support loaded on input line 3026.
Package cleveref Info: `aliascnt' support loaded on input line 3193.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/regexpatch/regexpatch.sty
Package: regexpatch 2021/03/21 v0.2f Extending etoolbox patching commands
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2022-01-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)))
\c@application=\count194
\c@assertion=\count195
\c@assumption=\count196
\c@axiom=\count197
\c@claim=\count198
\c@conclusion=\count199
\c@conjecture=\count266
\c@construction=\count267
\c@convention=\count268
\c@corollary=\count269
\c@definition=\count270
\c@example=\count271
\c@exercise=\count272
\c@fact=\count273
\c@hypothesis=\count274
\c@lemma=\count275
\c@notation=\count276
\c@observation=\count277
\c@postulate=\count278
\c@problem=\count279
\c@property=\count280
\c@proposition=\count281
\c@question=\count282
\c@recall=\count283
\c@remark=\count284
\c@theorem=\count285
\c@definition-proposition=\count286
\c@definition-theorem=\count287
\c@proposition-definition=\count288
\c@theorem-definition=\count289
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty
Package: thmtools 2020/08/01 v0.72
\thmt@toks=\toks22
\c@thmt@dummyctr=\count290
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty
Package: thm-patch 2020/08/01 v0.72
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty
Package: parseargs 2020/08/01 v0.72
\@parsespec=\toks23
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty
Package: thm-kv 2020/08/01 v0.72
Package thm-kv Info: Theorem names will be uppercased on input line 42.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex
```

With `xelatex`:

```
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-05-04> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty
Package: amsthm 2020/05/29 v2.20.6
\thm@style=\toks16
\thm@bodyfont=\toks17
\thm@headfont=\toks18
\thm@notefont=\toks19
\thm@headpunct=\toks20
\thm@preskip=\skip49
\thm@postskip=\skip50
\thm@headsep=\skip51
\dth@everypar=\toks21
) (/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/betas/create-theorem/create-theorem.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-05-04 L3 programming layer (loader) 
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2022-04-20 L3 backend support: XeTeX
\g__graphics_track_int=\count189
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count190
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count191
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count192
))
Package: l3keys2e 2022-01-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
Package: create-theorem 2022/05/22 Initializing theorem-like environments with multilingual support
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/aliascnt.sty
Package: aliascnt 2018/09/07 v1.5 Alias counters (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/local/betas/crefthe/crefthe.sty
Package: crefthe 2022/05/13 Cross referencing with proper definite articles
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cleveref/cleveref.sty
Package: cleveref 2018/03/27 v0.21.4 Intelligent cross-referencing
Package cleveref Info: `amsthm' support loaded on input line 3026.
Package cleveref Info: `aliascnt' support loaded on input line 3193.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/regexpatch/regexpatch.sty
Package: regexpatch 2021/03/21 v0.2f Extending etoolbox patching commands
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2022-01-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)))
\c@application=\count193
\c@assertion=\count194
\c@assumption=\count195
\c@axiom=\count196
\c@claim=\count197
\c@conclusion=\count198
\c@conjecture=\count199
\c@construction=\count266
\c@convention=\count267
\c@corollary=\count268
\c@definition=\count269
\c@example=\count270
\c@exercise=\count271
\c@fact=\count272
\c@hypothesis=\count273
\c@lemma=\count274
\c@notation=\count275
\c@observation=\count276
\c@postulate=\count277
\c@problem=\count278
\c@property=\count279
\c@proposition=\count280
\c@question=\count281
\c@recall=\count282
\c@remark=\count283
\c@theorem=\count284
\c@definition-proposition=\count285
\c@definition-theorem=\count286
\c@proposition-definition=\count287
\c@theorem-definition=\count288
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thmtools.sty
Package: thmtools 2020/08/01 v0.72
\thmt@toks=\toks22
\c@thmt@dummyctr=\count289
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-patch.sty
Package: thm-patch 2020/08/01 v0.72
 (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/parseargs.sty
Package: parseargs 2020/08/01 v0.72
\@parsespec=\toks23
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/thmtools/thm-kv.sty
Package: thm-kv 2020/08/01 v0.72
Package th
```

(It is not that I didn't copy it completely, it just stops at `th`, no matter how many times I tried)

Comment: I moved `\usepackage{thmtools}` after  `\usepackage{create-theorem}`  to make it work. First step was commenting out a package at a time.

Comment: @SimonDispa I moved it after but it still won't compile, perhaps we are using different version :(

Comment: If I change the name to `MYtheorem` I just have an error. So probably `theorem` is already defined somewhere and the package is not checking?

Comment: @Rmano That is because the heading names etc. are not preset for `MYtheorem`. However, when I explicitly specify the names, I got an error `Use of \??? doesn't match its definition.` Unfortunately this still doesn't provide enough information where has gone wrong :(

Comment: it loops because `\thetheorem_crthm_regional ` expands to itself.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. Do you happen to know why this error only occurs when `thmtools` is used? Is it because that somewhere in this package the counter gets expanded somehow?

Comment: no, it breaks because of \thmt@autorefsetup in thm-autoref. But I can't tell you why.

Comment: Direct cause is that `thmtools` redefines `\newtheorem`, which is used by `\CreateTheorem`. The original definition is let to `\thmt@original@newtheorem`. The root cause seems to be relevant to `\@counteralias` which is affected by default settings of `create-theorem` (for example counter `theorem` is pre-defined) and wrongly defines `\thmt@sibling` to be the same as `\thmt@envname`. I need more time to dig into this. Also I'm curious about if there's indeed the need to load both `thmtools` and `create-theorem`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you for the explanation. Regarding your "I'm curious" part, the problem is that many people tends to load tons of packages that they don't understand, so it would be better for us package author to eliminate as much conflicts as possible. For now I just redefine `\thmt@autorefsetup` to be empty, which shouldn't be a big problem since (to me) the users of `create-theorem` are expected use `\cref` instead of `\autoref` (or is there some necessary reason to use `\autoref`? I never tried this command, but from what I saw `\cref` seems to do everything it can do).

Comment: @Jinwen I'd recommend using `\thmt@original@newtheorem` instead of `\newtheorem` in `\crthm_create_theorem:nn`, when `thmtools` is loaded. Packages that share a large amount of utilities are harder to be compatible, especially when they use the same entrance (here `\newtheorem`). Also I don't think loading tons of packages without knowing their utilities is something that should be condoned.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you for this suggestion, I have modified my code. And for your "I don't think" part, I can't agree more, but I believe most of my classmates really don't care any of this technical issue and they would just throw everything that might be useful into their preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just answering "how to find the issue" (not how to fix it)

Add `\tracingall`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{create-theorem}

\tracingall
\CreateTheorem {theorem} {}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
    Text.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

After a while (running locally) you will see the log stabilize to:

```
~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional
```

which is obviously looping with `\thetheorem_crthm_regional` expanding to itself.  You can interupt with Ctrl-c:

```
~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 

~........\thetheorem_crthm_regional ->\thetheorem_crthm_regional 
! Interruption.
\cref@old@refstepcounter ...sname the#1\endcsname 
                                                  }
\refstepcounter@optarg ...@old@refstepcounter {#2}
                                                  \cref@constructprefix {#2}...

\cref@thmoptarg ...}\else \refstepcounter [#1]{#3}
                                                  \def \@tempa {\@oparg {\@b...

\environment theorem code ..._crthm_regional}[#1]}
                                                  \bool_if:NF \l__crthm_regi...

\l__cmd_tmpb_tl ->\__cmd_add_arg:o \c_novalue_tl 
                                                  
<to be read again> 
                   T
l.13     T
          ext.
?
```

at which point you can stop with `x`

```
? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on cc312.log.
```

Comment: Thank you, this explains "*it loops because `\thetheorem_crthm_regional`  expands to itself*", but I didn't see anything about `\thmt@autorefsetup` that Ulrike Fischer mentioned in another comment. Do you know how to trace the issue to this macro?

Comment: @Jinwen further up the log file, the ....regional command that evenually loops gets introduced by that setup command `~w..........\thmt@autorefsetup ->\@xa \def \csname \thmt@envname autorefname\@xa
 \endcsname \@xa {\thmt@thmname }\ifthmt@hassibling \@counteralias {\thmt@envna
me }{\thmt@sibling }\@xa \def \@xa \thmt@autoreffix \@xa {\@xa \let \csname the
\thmt@envname \@xa \endcsname \csname the\thmt@sibling \endcsname \def \thmt@au
toreffix {}}\protected@edef \thmt@sibling {\thmt@envname }\fi 
....
~...........\thmt@envname ->theorem_crthm_regional
`  But I didn't trace the details.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `thmtools` bug, for full analysis see https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/issues/27.

As a workaround, one can use

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{create-theorem}

\makeatletter
\IfPackageAtLeastTF{thmtools}{2022/01/01} % current version is 2021/05/27 v0.73
  {}
  {% \xpatchcmd is provided by `xpatchcmd` package, which is loaded by
   % `crefthe`, which is loaded by `create-theorem`.
    \xpatchcmd\thmt@autorefsetup
      {\@xa\let\csname the\thmt@envname\@xa\endcsname}
      {\@xa\global\@xa\let\csname the\thmt@envname\@xa\endcsname}
      {}{\PatchFailed}
  }
\makeatother

\CreateTheorem { theorem } {}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
    Text.
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For now I'm using `\hook_gput_code:nnn { package/thmtools/after } { crthm } { \cs_gset_eq:NN \crthm_newtheorem:w \thmt@original@newtheorem }` to use the original `\newtheorem` as you suggested yesterday. Do you think that it would be suffice and continue to work for future versions? (By the way, after a bit thinking, I realize that `thmtools` has a wonderful interface for setting theorem styles so it should not be that strange to use `thmtools` and `create-theorem` together :)

Comment: @Jinwen A bugfix new version of `thmtools` (v0.73) is just uploaded to CTAN. Let's see if there's new compatibility problems. It seems to me that `create-theorem` always calls `\newtheorem`, but the full power of `thmtools` is only possible with `\declaretheorem`. Perhaps `create-theorem` wants to provide an interface to setting `thmtools` options, and then call `\declaretheorem`. Personally speaking, the implementation of `thmtools` is not as attractive as its utilities and I'll only do bug fix, no (big) new features. Another attraction level above it would just make debugging more suffering.

Comment: @Jinwen Just thought of, maybe `\hook_gput_code:nnn { package/thmtools/before } { crthm } { \cs_gset_eq:NN \crthm_newtheorem:w \newtheorem }` is better. It's independent of the internal name `thmtools` chooses and only relevant to the fact that `thmtools` will modify `\newtheorem`.

Comment: Thank you for this. `thmtools` shall (for a long time) serve as an inspiration to me. I would still use `\newtheorem` instead of `\declaretheorem` in my package but gradually I shall try to reproduce those useful functionality of `thmtools` into `\CreateTheorem` (at the time of creating this package my sole purpose was to provide multilingual and clever referencing support, since `thmtools` has already done well on the other things). Thank you for your maintenance anyway, nice work :)

Comment: With `\hook_gput_code:nnn { package/thmtools/before } { crthm } { \cs_gset_eq:NN \crthm_newtheorem:w \newtheorem }` if one loads `thmtools` before `create-theorem` there shall be a problem.

Comment: @Jinwen I only did several minor changes to `thmtools` since 2020, the glory belongs to its author Dr. Ulrich M. Schwarz. For the hook issue, it seems sth like `\IfPackageLoadedTF{thmtools}{\cs_gset_eq:NN \crthm_newtheorem:w \thmt@original@newtheorem}{\cs_gset_eq:NN \crthm_newtheorem:w \newtheorem}` suffices? Don't know what I was thinking about before.